# Nest.js FileInterceptor wait for file to be moved

Tags: node.js, nestjs, multer

I have a problem with fetching the image right after upload. Here's my back-end code, that's working:

```
@Post('upload')
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor('file', {
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: join(__dirname, '../../../', 'static/files'),
        filename: async (req, file, callback) => {
          const fileExtName = extname(file.originalname);
          const randomName = await randomUUID();
          await callback(null, `${randomName}${fileExtName}`);
        },
      }),
    }),
  )
  async uploadFile(
    @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
  ): Promise<DataResponseDto<UploadedFileDto>> {
    const url = `${this.configService.apiConfig.apiStaticUrl}/${file.filename}`;
    return { data: { uploadedFileUrl: url } };
  }
```

The problem is that when I fetch the image right after upload, I get an HTTP error 503. Meaning the file hasn't been moved to the static folder before being fetched.

How can I wait for it to be moved in the controller, before returning the image URL?

Comment: It depends, as usual. You could start with `awaiting` in the interceptor until the file is saved. Alternatively, you can have a function called in `uploadFile` that keeps checking if the file is created by the interceptor. Keep in mind that no matter the approach you choose, you need to make sure to have some sort of timeout.

Comment: I don't find anything you said useful unfortunately. There's no way you can await for the file save in the interceptor, there no function call inside of it. The only possible solution I came up with myself, is to extend the FileInterceptor somehow and do something inside that, but I'm not entirely sure how to do that either.

Comment: That's what I meant. You can either extend the `FileInterceptor` or create your own custom `StorageEngine`. See [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) (especially at the end) and [this](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/StorageEngine.md) for further help. As for the second part, you can use node's resources to check if the file exists, for example, [`existsSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsexistssyncpath).